# Possible memory leak in Python?

Tags: python

1. I'm experiencing an issue when calling a function inside a while loop.
   The purpose of the while loop is to perform an action ,but it can only perform this action if a certain threshold appeared. This threshold is a result from another function.
2. When running this for the first time ,everything works ok. No threshold -no run.
3. The problem is ,that this threshold is affected by other parameters ,and when it changes ,it usually blocks the main program from running.
   But ,at certain times, which I cannot pinpoint precisely when ,there's a "slip" and the threshold does not prevent the main program from running.
4. My question is ,could there be a memory leakage of some sort?
5. Code is below ,thanks.

```
    def pre_run_check():
        if check_outside() != 1:
            return (0)
        else:
            return(1)
    
    
    if __name__== '__main__':
    while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            allow_action = None
            while allow_action == None:
                print ("cannot run")
                try:
                    allow_action = pre_run_check()
                except:
                    allow_action = 0
            else:
                if allow_action == 1:
                    print ("running")
                    #take action of some sort##
                    allow_action = None
```

Comment: Please be more specific in the side effects you’re experiencing.  (What’s occurring vs what you’re expecting)

Comment: It's not impossible that there are memory leaks, but I cannot see how that would affect this code in any way.  You will have to provide a lot more information.  I'm sure you realize that it's much more likely that YOU have a bug than Python has a bug.

Comment: where is check_outside function defined?

Comment: When you run the loop, `allow_action` is always being set to something other than `None`; there is no way for this loop to continue, it's pointless unless you change the values to have a possibility of being `None`.

Comment: you missed sequential process rules. It's not memory leak, you freeze process events. All `While True` casting need a `break`.

Comment: Python, like almost any garbage-collected language can have a memory leak, kind of, but that does not seem to be the case in your code. This can happen when you unknowingly hold a reference to an object, making it linger. One of the most common ways to get such a reference in Python is when you create and return a function. It is easy to accidentally let this function hold references to objects you don't really need, and are not aware of. If this function is a callback, it may live forever effectively leaking the object.

Comment: Is your last `else` supposed to be part of the `try-except` structure? The indentation does no look right.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pre_run_check():
    if check_outside() != 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True


while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    allow_action = pre_run_check()
    while not allow_action:
        print ("cannot run")
        try:
            allow_action = pre_run_check()
            if allow_action :
                print ("running")
                #take action of some sort##
                allow_action = False
                #Actualy need wait end of subprocess, Otherwise got some corrupted data/handle
                break
        except:
            allow_action = False
        time.sleep(.5)
```

This point is *how to generate an sequential Process*
Hope its helps.

Comment: Thanks ,can you please explain how you would:"#Actualy need wait end of subprocess, Otherwise got some corrupted data/handle" ?

Comment: Processing the right data at the same time is an important detail. Sometimes the value you read may conflict with the data that has been processed. If you are considering a synchronous application, you must specify which data will be valid and when it will be ignored.All functions must return a data. time sleep may cause you to return incorrect data or become unrelated. Have nice day.